Nginx subdomain error, subdoamin always go to root folder of main domain
I create subdomain on nginx ,
I have made a configuration on sites-available and have also symlinked it to sites-enabled,
I have also added records to cloudflare, for example
Type: A
name : Blog
content : IP
but when I opened a subdomain, the subdomain opened the root folder of the main domain even though I had already set it in the subdomain configuration like /var/www/panel/ while the one opened by the subdomain is /var/www/wordpress which is the root directory of the main domain
here the configuration of main domain

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    root /var/www/wordpress;
    index index.php index.html index.nginx-debian.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/example_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/example_access.log;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/example.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/example.key;

    root /var/www/wordpress;
    index index.php index.html index.nginx-debian.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/example_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/example_access.log;
}

here the configuration of subdomain
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name panel.example.com www.panel.example.com;

    root /var/www/panel;
    index index.php index.html index.nginx-debian.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
    }
}


Please post the relevant Nginx configuration. Also, I just have to ask, did you reload/restart Nginx after making these changes?

Yes, im reload and restart the Nginx after making that changes

When you test the subdomain, are you using HTTP or HTTPS?

When i try request using HTTPS it being direct to HTTPS

I’m not certain what that means exactly. But you only have SSL configured for one of the sites.
